# How to specify User Agent and Referer in FileUtils.copyURLToFile(URL, File) method?

Tags: java, apache, http-headers, apache-commons

I'm using **[`FileUtils.copyURLToFile(URL, File)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile(java.net.URL,%20java.io.File))**, an [Apache Commons IO 2.4](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) part, to download and save the file on my computer. The problem is that some sites refuse connection without referrer and user agent data.

My questions:

1. Is there any way to specify user agent and referrer to the `copyURLToFile` method?
2. Or should I use another approach to download a file and then save a given `InputStream` to file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've re-implement the functionality with `HttpComponents` instead of `Commons-IO`. This code allows you to download a file in Java according to its URL and save it at the specific destination.

*The final code:*

```
public static boolean saveFile(URL imgURL, String imgSavePath) {

    boolean isSucceed = true;

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(imgURL.toString());
    httpGet.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.11 Safari/537.36");
    httpGet.addHeader("Referer", "https://www.google.com");

    try {
        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity imageEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        if (imageEntity != null) {
            FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(imageEntity.getContent(), new File(imgSavePath));
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        isSucceed = false;
    }

    httpGet.releaseConnection();

    return isSucceed;
}
```

Of course, the code above takes more space then just single line of code:

```
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(imgURL, new File(imgSavePath),
                        URLS_FETCH_TIMEOUT, URLS_FETCH_TIMEOUT);
```

but it will give you more control over a process and let you specify not only timeouts but `User-Agent` and `Referer` values, which are critical for many web-sites.

Answer (score 1):

Completing the accepted answer on how to handle timeouts:

If you want to set timeouts, you have to create the `CloseableHttpClient` like this:

```java
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                 .setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeout)
                 .setConnectionRequestTimeout(readDataTimeout)
                 .setSocketTimeout(readDataTimeout)
                 .build();

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder
                 .create()
                 .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
                 .build();
```

And, it may be a good idea to create your `CloseableHttpClient` using a try-with-resource statement to handle its closing:

```java
try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build()) {
  ... rest of the code using httpClient
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, unless you can get a hold of the underlying mechanism that opens the URL.

I recommend to use the https://hc.apache.org/ library. This has a lot of features regarding headers etc.

Comment: I already use `Apache HttpComponents` but don't know how to combine the functionality of `copyURLToFile` and `HttpComponents`.

Comment: you don't use the copyToUrl, you can use https components nio package and use a file channel to write the data to a file